# SQLite: Merging the contents of 2 columns into 1?

Tags: sqlite

How do I merge the contents of two columns into one in SQLite?  I'm not looking to union 2 columns, I just want SQLite to automatically copy the entire contents of two columns and dump them (in any order) into a single column.  For example, suppose I have the following table:

```
Table1:

Column1:      Column2:

Red,          Yellow
Green,        Red
Blue,         Gold
Purple,       Green
Black,        White

And this is the desired result:

Red
Green
Blue
Purple
Black
Yellow
Red
Gold
Green
White
```

What's the simplest SQLite query that'll get to the desired result?

I tried the following: `Select Column1 || Column2 FROM Table1;`

But I got the undesired result:

```
RedYellow
GreenRed
BlueGold
PurpleGreen
BlackWhite
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that UNION ALL should give you the result:

```
Select Column1 AS Column_1_2 FROM Table1
UNION ALL
Select Column2 AS Column_1_2 FROM Table1;
```